# JSP - get url to servlet by servlet name

Tags: jsp, servlets

In Servlet we have annotation:

```
@WebServlet(name = "myOwnSite", value = "/siteHere")
```

It is possible to generate URI `/siteHere` in JSP by servlet name `myOwnSite`?

Comment: Say what......?

Comment: I mean that, reffering to servlet name get path of this servlet. If you write something in `twig`, this is equivalent of `path`

Answer (score 1):

The annotation should be

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/yoururl"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{}
```

For accessing the parameter in annotation, use reflection:

```
//somewhere you want to get the url
String[] patterns=MyServlet.class.getAnnotation(WebServlet.class).urlPatterns();
```

Comment: Good idea with reflection, but JAVA ee does'nt provide method for this?

Comment: No, urlPatterns is not really meant to be reference by application.